# Почему исходный код cgi-скрипта при запросе отображается в браузере, но сам скрипт не выводит html-разметку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, python-3.5

Делал все как здесь: https://pythonworld.ru/web/cgi-1.html

Код скрипта:

```
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print(
"""<html>
<body>
<h1>GOTO HELL</h1>
</body>
</html>""")
```

Пользовался самописным веб-сервером на Python:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("localhost", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Должно выводиться **GOTO HELL**, но получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как захендлить скрипт на исполнение в самописном веб-сервере на Python?

Comment: смотрите настройки web-сервера. Скорее всего не прописан обработчик CGI (AddHandler cgi-script .py(для апача))

Comment: [Полный cgi пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30516779/4279). Начните со стандартного сервера (когда заработает ваш cgi-скрипт, тогда можете на свой сервер переходить—отлаживайте одну проблему за раз). Положите в нужную директорию (cgi-bin отличается от cgi_bin) Добавьте shebang (`#!`) и разрешение на выполнение если нужно. Убедитесь, нужная (третья) версия питона используется (а не вторая).

Comment: хм... у меня всё работает. Странно.
У вас какая ОС?

Comment: ОС - Windows 10.